# Date conversion from Angular to Java

Tags: java, angular, spring

Hi I am using Moment Date which is currently in this format `Tue Dec 07 2021 11:57:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
This date is being as request param to call an api, and the api goes like this:

```
public @ResponseBody Response updateAll( 
        @RequestParam(name = "effective-dt", required = false) Date effectiveDt) {
         /***Business Logic***/
       }
```

new Date() returns `Tue Dec 07 11:52:52 IST 2021` and angular is trying to send `Tue Dec 07, 2021, 11:57:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` how do I make angular to send the date-time in Java Date Format

Comment: You should be ssending the date in the iso date/time format for conversion not some arbitraty string.

Comment: @Abra not actually i would like to recieve in date format itself, no conversions at backend

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried sending '2021-12-01T09:49:11.000Z' as request param, unfortunately recieved 400 bad request

Comment: Don't use `java.util.Date` as that is flawed by design from the start. Use `LocalDateTime` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import moment, {Moment, MomentInputObject} from 'moment/moment';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ToolsDateService {
    
    convertStringToDateWithCustomFormat(date: Moment | Date | string | number | (number | string)[] | MomentInputObject, format: string): Date {
        return moment(date, format).toDate();
    }
}
```

you can use moment lib to work with date if you need to change all date fields
to your custom format, you can implement HttpInterceptor and check
if response data instance of date convert data to your custom format

for more information please check this link
[Angular 5, HttpClient changes Date fields to UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495948/angular-5-httpclient-changes-date-fields-to-utc)